# Adventures with the untyped lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, types, lambda-calculus

We occasionally have people ask about implementing the untyped lambda calculus in Haskell. [Naturally, I now cannot *find* any of these questions, but I'm sure I've seen them!] Just for giggles, I thought I'd spend some time playing with this.

It's trivial enough to do something like

```
i = \ x -> x
k = \ x y -> x
s = \ f g x -> (f x) (g x)
```

This works perfectly. However, as soon as you try to do something like

```
s i i
```

the type-checker rightly complains about an infinite type. Basically *everything* in the untyped lambda calculus is a function — which essentially means all functions have *infinite* arity. But Haskell only allows functions of finite arity. (Because, really, why would you want infinite arity?)

Well, it turns out we can easily side-step that limitation:

```
data Term = T (Term -> Term)

T f ! x = f x

i = T $ \ x -> x
k = T $ \ x -> T $ \ y -> x
s = T $ \ f -> T $ \ g -> T $ \ x -> (f ! x) ! (g ! x)
```

This works perfectly, and allows arbitrary lambda expressions to be constructed and executed. For example, we can easily build a function to turn an `Int` into a Church numeral:

```
zero = k ! i
succ = s ! (s ! (k ! s) ! k)

encode 0 = zero
encode n = succ ! (encode $ n-1)
```

Again, this works perfectly.

Now write a decode function.

…yeah, good luck with that! The trouble is, we can *create* arbitrary lambda terms, but we can't *inspect* them in any way. So we need to add some way to do that.

---

So far, the best idea I've come up with is this:

```
data Term x = F (Term x -> Term x) | R (Term x -> x)

F f ! x =            f x
R f ! x = R $ \ _ -> f x

out :: Term x -> x
out (R f) = f (error "mu")
out (F _) =   (error "nu")

i = F $ \ x -> x
k = F $ \ x -> F $ \ y -> x
s = F $ \ f -> F $ \ g -> F $ \ x -> (f ! x) ! (g ! x)
```

I can now do something like

```
decode :: Term Int -> Int
decode ti = out $ ti ! R (\ tx -> 1 + out tx) ! R (\ tx -> 0)
```

This works great for Church Bools and Church numerals.

---

Things start to go horribly wrong when I start trying to do anything high-order. Having thrown away all the type information to implement the *untyped* lambda calculus, I'm now struggling to convince the type checker to let me do what I want to do.

This works:

```
something = F $ \ x -> F $ \ n -> F $ \ s -> s ! x
nothing   =            F $ \ n -> F $ \ s -> n

encode :: Maybe x -> Term x
encode (Nothing) = nothing
encode (Just  x) = something ! x
```

This does not:

```
decode :: Term x -> Maybe (Term x)
decode tmx = out $ tmx ! R (\ tx -> Nothing) ! R (\ tx -> Just tx)
```

I've tried a dozen slight variations on this; none of them type-check. It's not that I don't understand why it fails, but rather than I can't figure out any way for it to succeed. (Most particularly, `R Just` is clearly ill-typed.)

It's almost as if I want a function `forall x y. Term x -> Term y`. Because, for *pure* untyped terms, this should always be possible. It's only terms involving `R` where that won't work. But I can't figure out how to phrase that in the Haskell type system.

(For example, try changing the type of `F` to `forall x. Term x -> Term x`. Now the definition of `k` is ill-typed, since the inner `F $ \ y -> x` cannot actually return *any* type, but only the [now fixed] type of `x`.)

Any anybody smarter than me have a better idea?

Answer (score 5):

OK, I've found *a* solution:

The code above has `Term x`, parameterised by the result type for `R`. Instead of doing that (and freaking out the type checker), construct some type `Value` that can represent every result type you will ever want to return. Now we have

```
data Term = F (Term -> Term) | R (Term -> Value)
```

Having collapsed all possible result types into a single opaque `Value` type, we can do our work.

Concretely, the type I chose is

```
data Value = V Int [Term]
```

So a `Value` is an `Int` representing an ADT value constructor, followed by one `Term` for each field of that constructor. With this definition, we can finally do

```
decode :: Term -> Maybe Term
decode tmx =
  case tmx ! R (\ _ -> V 0 []) ! R (\ tx -> V 1 [tx]) of
    V 0 []   -> Nothing
    V 1 [tx] -> Just tx
    _        -> error "not a Maybe"
```

Similarly, you can encode and decode lists like so:

```
null =                        F $ \ n -> F $ \ c -> n
cons = F $ \ x -> n $ \ xs -> F $ \ n -> F $ \ c -> c ! x ! xs

encode :: [Term] -> Term
encode (  []) = null
encode (x:xs) = cons ! x ! encode xs

decode :: Term -> [Term]
decode txs =
  case out $ txs ! R (\ txs -> V 0 []) ! F (\ tx -> R $ \ txs -> V 1 [tx, txs]) of
    V 0 []        -> []
    V 1 [tx, txs] -> tx : decode txs
    _             -> error "not a list"
```

Of course, you have to *guess* which decode function(s) you need to apply. But that's the untyped lambda calculus for you!

Comment: I think `data Term = Lam (Term -> Term) | App Term Term | Var Int` would be a more straightforward solution.

Comment: @András Kovács, did you mean `Lam Term`?

Comment: @user3237465 no, I meant `Term -> Term`. We can do a [similar answer](http://lpaste.net/136328) as above, but IMO cleaner.

Comment: @András Kovács, ah, see now. This is much like `quote` from [the shortest beta-normalizer](http://fplab.bitbucket.org/posts/2008-04-13-the-shortest-betanormaliz.html) (other authors call this function `readback`).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but commenting is too restrictive.

`R Just` is ill-typed, because its type is recursive, but we can always wrap this type-level recursion in a data type:

```
data Fix2 g f = Fix2 { run :: g (f (Fix2 g f)) }
```

`Fix2` can be represented in terms of `Fix` and composition of type constructors, but I don't want to complicate things.

Then we can define `decode` as

```
decode :: Term (Fix2 Maybe Term) -> Maybe (Term (Fix2 Maybe Term))
decode tmx = run $ out $ tmx ! R (Fix2 . const Nothing) ! R (Fix2 . Just)
```

Some tests:

```
isSomething :: Term (Fix2 Maybe Term) -> Bool
isSomething = isJust . decode

i = F id

main = do
    print $ isSomething (something ! i) -- True
    print $ isSomething  nothing        -- False
```

But clearly `Term (Fix2 Maybe Term)` is far from `Term a`.